# Did the Prophet forbid Hind bint Utbah from coming in front of him?

Tags: hadith, source-identification, authenticity

It has come to my hearing several times that the beloved prophet Muhammad (pbuh) forbade Hinda, the wife of Abu Sufyan to come in front of him, for she had been responsible for the killing of his uncle, Hamzah.

Is this a fabrication? Is there any source of reference for this?

Comment: What is known is that the prophet () asked Wahshi the -former- slave who killed his uncle Hamzah to stay close to him when he accepted Islam (see [her](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:4072)). As for Hind there are ahadith telling us that she even spoke to prophet () (see [here](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/93/43).

Comment: Any reference to this?

Comment: https://sunnah.com/bukhari:7180

Comment: @The Z, It is off-target. It is not even relevant.

Comment: It is just to support the point that Hind talked to the Prophet (SAW) and it is reported in many hadith. So, this doesn't seem to be true.

Comment: Alright. I thought you provided a reference to what I sought.

Comment: Well the hadith clearly says otherwise so it is what you sought!

Answer (score 2):

Your post has many mistakes therefore my answer will focus on their clarification.

**Who ordered the killing of Hamza?**

First of all Hind () was not responsible for killing Hamzah ibn 'Abd al-Muttalib().

As the -former slave- Wahshy was the slave of [Jubayr ibn Mut'im](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jubayr_ibn_Mu%E1%B9%AD%CA%BDim), who bribed him to do so as a revenge for the killing of his uncle in the battle of Badr.

> ..."Will you tell us (the story of) the killing of Hamza?" Wahshi replied "Yes, Hamza killed Tuaima bin 'Adi bin Al-Khaiyar at Badr (battle) so my master, Jubair bin Mut'im said to me, 'If you kill Hamza in revenge for my uncle, then you will be set free." ... ([Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:4072))

**Who was asked to hide his face from the prophet(), due to the killing of Hamzah()?**

In the same source as stated above Wahshy reports how he accepted Islam saying:

> ... I was told that the Prophet (ﷺ) did not harm the messengers; So I too went out with them till I reached Allah's Messenger (ﷺ). When he saw me, he said, 'Are you Wahshi?' I said, 'Yes.' He said, 'Was it you who killed Hamza?' I replied, 'What happened is what you have been told of.' He said, '**Can you hide your face from me**?' So I went out when Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) died, and Musailamah Al-Kadhdhab appeared (claiming to be a prophet). ..

Please note that this was the first time the prophet () met Wahshy at least after the battle of Uhud.
Al-Jubayr ibn Mut'im also accepted Islam and reported at least two known sahih ahadith so he certainly didn't hide his face or stood away from our prophet ().

**What is the relation between Hind bint 'Utbah () and the killing of Hamzah()**

There are many strange narrations about Hind saying that she ate (from) the liver of Hamzah () after his death. None of them reaches a level of authenticity. However it was common in Jahilyah to mutilate the death of the enemies and it is very likely that she did.

> "The Messenger of Allah came to Hamza on the Day of Uhud, he stood over him and **saw that he had been mutilated**. He said: Had it not been that Safiyyah would be distressed, then I would have left him to be eaten by the beasts until he was gathered on the Day of Judgment from their stomachs." He said: "Then he called for a Namirah to shroud him with. When it was extended over his head, it left his feet exposed, and when it was extended over his feet, it left his head exposed." He said: "There were many dead and few cloths." He said: "One, two and three men were shrouded in one cloth and buried in one grave." He said: "So the Messenger of Allah was asking which of them knew the most Quran, so he could put him toward the Qibalh." He said: "So the Messenger of Allah buried them and he did not perform (funeral prayers) for them." ([Jami' at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:1016))

**Reported meetings between Hind and the prophet ()**

In fact the sunnah at least provides two examples of meetings between the prophet () and Hind. The first was when she accepted Islam:

> Hind bint 'Utba bin Rabi'a came and said. "O Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)! By Allah, there was no family on the surface of the earth, I like to see in degradation more than I did your family, but today there is no family on the surface of the earth whom I like to see honored more than yours." Hind added, "Abu Sufyan is a miser. Is it sinful of me to feed our children from his property?" The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "There is no blame on you if you feed them (thereof) in a just and reasonable manner.
> (Sahih al-Bukhari [here](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:7161) and in other versions [here](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6641), [here](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3825) and also in [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1714d))

Note that this was her first meeting with Muhammad () after the battle of Uhud and as pointed out above it would make sense if the prophet () really saw any relation between the killing of his uncle and her, he'd ask her to hide her face from him, but he didn't in fact he answered her inquiry and it could even be that they met again as stated in the sahih hadith:

> Hind bint 'Utba (Abu Sufyan's wife) came and said, "O Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)! Abu Sufyan is a miser. Is there any harm if I spend something from his property for our children?" He said, there is no harm for you if you feed them from it justly and reasonably (with no extravagance).
> (See in Sahih al-Bukhari [here](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:2460), [here](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5359), [here](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5364))

**Note:** This doesn't mean that maybe other people were also asked to hide their faces for other reasons. But this is not the topic of this question.

Comment: It was very encouraging to see such an effort on your part. May Allah help you.